# How do i create an accordion control similar to one created using AJAX in IOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, accordion

I want create an accordion control similar to one created using AJAX http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx where I can place icons instead of text for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to use an expandable `UITableView` - when you tap a cell you reveal a number of cells beneath it (the contents of your accordion). You don't *necessarily* need to use a table view, but typically it's a good starting point.

There are a couple of controllers that have been put out in the open - [this one, for example](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uiexpandabletableview) - but it's not too difficult to write yourself once you know a bit about table views and removing/adding cells.