# UITableView submenu

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, user-interface

I'm looking to create a menu with collapsible submenus in my iOS app. It should look something like this:

```
Main menu item 1
    Submenu item 1
    Submenu item 2
    Submenu item 3
Main menu item 2
    Submenu item 1
    Submenu item 2
```

I don't want the drill-down approach Apple does with `UINavigationController` since the submenus are few (1-3) and have very short titles. I also want to be able to collapse or expand submenus when a corresponding main menu item is tapped.

I don't see how I can coax `UITableView` to do this so I'm thinking I have to do my own control unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: Basically you want an accordion effect right? Look at this [post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576555/how-do-i-create-an-accordion-control-similar-to-one-created-using-ajax-in-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a sample code from Apple, have a look and create one which you need
[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: There is a bug in this sample but... its idea is great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sectioned table view where the section headers are actually your main menu items. The cells in that section would correspond to your submenu items. Use tap gestures on the section headers to expand and contract.